# Trying to figure out why my regex command won't work

Tags: grep

I have a problem to work on and was wondering why my regex won't work. It's a simple exercise to match words in a text dictionary that contains the top row. I believe I have a solution but grep comes up blank every time:

```
grep ^[qwertyuiop]+$ /opt/~~~~~~/data/web2
```

this is my command, which does nothing, but if i just put:

```
grep [qwertyuiop] /opt/~~~~~~/data/web2
```

it matches words with letters from the top row. Can anybody tell me why it isn't working? Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Add `-E` to your `grep` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're super close.
With grep you want to use the `-x` flag to match the whole line.

```
grep -x '[qwertyuiop]\+' /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

then a simple *escaped* `+` to match multiple characters.

if you want to avoid the -x you can take your original approach like so:

```
grep '^[qwertyuiop]\+$' /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

With an escape and some quotes it works marvelously, although i think the `-x` is more idiomatic, as some other people have commented,  you can also get away with using `-e` although that can have some unintended consequences. I recommend `man grep` which gives a nice overview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think grep recognizes `^` `$` or `+` on it's own. You have to use `grep -e` or `egrep` to use special characters like that

Comment: You just need an escape.